# Cannot Configured Oracle local DB ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I've installed oracle 11g express edition on my machine and successfully add user and grant access using Run SQL COMMAND LINE, however I cannot configured it using SQL DEVELOPER that's where I encountered the above error. I've compared my configurations (tnsnames.ora and listener.ora) to other working machines and found with the same config.

Also I can longer access this site http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950:1:384148910814731

```
tnsname.ora

    XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = win)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  ) 

listener.ora

    SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = win)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Comment: `HOST = win` ping this host in the command line and check if this hostnme is responding. Check your firewall configuration and allow incoming and ooutgoing TCP connections to port 1521 on host `win`. Use `win` as hostname in SQL-Developer.

Comment: Also, is this the only tnsnames file on your whole machine? I used to end up with multiple tnsnames files and It was a battle to make sure which one was in use

Comment: What is connect string you use ?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies, appreciate it really but lucky I resolve it, I removed the IP and PC Name on C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc.